# Boost asio - reading and writing at the same time

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety, boost-asio

I'm trying to implement a two way communication using boost:asio. I'm writing the server that will communicate with multiple clients.

I want the writes and reads to and from clients to happen without any synchronization and order - the client can send a command to the server at any time and it still receives some data in a loop. Of course access to shared resources must be protected.

What is the best way to achieve this? Is having two threads - one for reading and one for writing a good option? What about accepting the connections and managing many clients?

//edit

By "no synchronization and order" I mean that the server should stream to the clients its data all the time and that it can respond(change its behaviour) to clients requests at any time regardless of what is now being sent to them.

Comment: You will probably need a thread for each read and each write channel per client and one extra to manage incoming connections.

Answer (score 4):

One key idea behind asio is exactly that you don't need multiple threads to deal with multiple client sessions. Your description is a bit generic, and I'm not sure I understand what you mean by 'I want the writes and reads to and from clients to happen without any synchronization and order'.

A good starting point would be the asio [chat server](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/boost_asio/examples.html) example. Notice how in this example an instance of the class `chat_session` is created for each connected client. Objects of that class keep on posting asynchronous reads as long as the connection is alive and at the same time they can write data to the connected clients. In the mean time an object of class `chat_server` keeps accepting new incoming client connections.

Comment: Do you mean that it's sufficient to just schedule the async work - reads and writes and just carry on ?

Comment: yes, in general, if you choose the asynchronuous versions of read, write or accept, you provide a callback that will be invoked when that operation finishes. The callback will run on any one thread associated with your io_service. A common scenario is where the callback for the accept completion schedules a read on the socket and the callback for that read schedules one or more write actions on a number of sockets, but also schedules the next read etc. This is in a nutshell what happens in the chat server example

Comment: On the 'and just carry on': actually you _do_ need to call the io_services `run`-method. Any thread that calls the `run`-method  will be used to run callbacks, as long as there is work to do (outstanding asynchronous read, write or accepts for instance).

Comment: The chat server example shows async_write called at start and in an async_read completion handler. In other words there is never an async_read or async_write executing concurrently with another.

Comment: @evoskuil: Strictly speaking you are right, the **functions** `async_read()` and `async_write()` are not running concurrently. However, you seem to suggest that this means that no concurrent write- or read actions are taking place and that would be incorrect: the two functions mentioned above will potentially (and likely) return before the asynchronous (read-/write-) operation has finished. Asynchronous read operations are taking place concurrently with asynchronous write operations.

Comment: @evoskuil: In other words:
The point of asio--or the proactor design pattern--is that there is [concurrency without the need for multiple threads](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/async.html).

Comment: There is a difference between not needing multiple threads and being unable to support operation with multiple threads.  The async functions accept an io_service which does cause operations to be invoked on multiple threads if there is more than one thread running as part of the service. This is however broken in the case of larger sized async write operations, as they will become interleaved on the socket.

Answer (score 1):

At work we're doing something conceptually very similar and there I noticed the big impact a heavy handler has on performance. The writing side of the code/write handler does too much work and occupies a worker thread for too long, thereby jeopardizing the program flow. Especially RST packets (closed connections) weren't detected quick enough by the read handler because the write actions were taking their sweet time and hogging most of the processing time in the worker thread. Currently I fixed that by creating two worker threads so that one line of code was not starved of processing time. Admittedly, this is far from ideal and it is on my lengthy to-do list of optimizations.

Long story short, you can get away with using a single thread for reading and writing if your handlers are light-weight while a second thread handles the rest of your program. Once you notice weird synchronization issues it's time to either lighten your network handlers or add an extra thread to the worker pool.